# Remove background with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

Here is my solution for getting a binary image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('crop.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
ok,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.imshow('threshold',thresh)

k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff
if k == ord('q'):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Below is the result I get. How can I remove background from hand?

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cORNE.png)
[threshold image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66ZfS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use color detection to get a mask for hand region. If you want to do background subtraction on video, then that can be achieved by storing the background and subtracting the upcoming frames from the background.

```
import cv2
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(1)
j=0
while 1:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    if(j==0):
        bg=frame.copy().astype("float")
    if(j<30):
        cv2.accumulateWeighted(frame,bg,0.5)
        j=j+1
    diff=cv2.absdiff(frame,bg.astype("uint8"))
    diff=cv2.cvtColor(diff,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thre,diff=cv2.threshold(diff,25,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv2.imshow("j",diff)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF==ord('q')):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I, indeed, try to subtract background on video for detecting number of fingers. Beside your solution, I found that already implemented background subtractor algorithms in opencv really come in handy, but the problem is my hand need to keep moving in region of interest, which is not so friendly in interaction.